# Error when using custom typescript paths in nativescript within an nx workspace

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, nrwl

I'm having some trouble using custom paths in a nativescript app which has been created within an nx workspace.

When running `npm run start.android`, I'm getting the following error:

`Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "@libs/installations/installations.component", relative to: app/tns_modules/`

I need to use custom typescript paths (set in tsconfig.json) in order to be able to import shared libaries within the nx workspace into the nativescript app.

Example paths:

```
"paths": {
    "@b2b/*": [
        "apps/b2b/src/app/*"
    ],
    "installations/*": [
        "dist/installations/*"
    ],
    "@libs/installations/*": [
        "libs/installations/src/lib/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Not directly related to the issue but a suggestion. The NativeScript organization is now working on creating nativescript-schematics https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-schematics - which is a tool for creating a code-sharing project (like the NX monorepo) for Angular Web and NativeScript Angular.